# How to graph a seasonality plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to build a graph to determine the seasonality of the influenza virus from January to December and group it per year (2011-2018), but I have problems with my results.

I would like graphics like the one that appear in this publication : https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0193263

```
outcome<- factor(c(rep("positive", 60)))
month<- sample(1:12,60,replace=T)
year <- sample(2011:2018,60,replace=T)
data<- data.frame(outcome, month, year)
ggplot(data, aes(x=month, y= frequency(data$outcome),
                 group = year, fill = year)) + geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  count(year, month , wt = outcome == "positive") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=month, y= n, group = year, fill = year)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12, labels = month.abb)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the first graphic in the paper the easiest way to do this is a `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid`.

Edit- I would also like to add that R does not do block comments like `***` if that's what you were trying.